# android: WebView and @font-face, reloads the font each time

Tags: android, performance, webview, truetype

I'm using @font-face/loadDataWithBaseURL to use my own font in a WebView. It works, but I'm facing a performance problem. Each time I change the contents of the WebView with "loadDataWithBaseURL", it reloads the font, and it tooks some seconds.

Disabling the @font-face, the performance is perfect.

The TTF is placed in assets, and the css/html are loaded together each time from a String.

Tryed to use cache, but it seems to use a file in storage memory, so maybe it makes no difference.
Or maybe I used it wrongly...

```
    myWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*20);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
```

Help, please.

More info:

The application memory usage keeps growing and growing in each loaddata.

Android version 2.3.5.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very ugly way to get it barely working. There is still some memory leak, but not as much as before.

It consist in removing the WebView and creating it again without destroying it before.

In that way it remembers the font! Don't ask me why, I can't understand it.

"ll1" is my LinearLayout, where the WebView is always the last view.

```
    LayoutParams lparams = myWebView.getLayoutParams();
    ll1.removeView(myWebView);
    myWebView = new WebView(myWebView.getContext());
    myWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, "text/html", null, null);
    myWebView.setOnTouchListener(this);
    myWebView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    myWebView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
    ll1.addView(myWebView);
```

Maybe the memory leak is because I do not destroy nor make null the object prior to creating again, but this is the only way I found to get it working with decent speed and memory usage.

I hope someone can explain this behaviour or give a better solution.